# How to use predict for linear regression using grouped independent variables in R?

Tags: r, group-by, linear-regression, lm

I made a model for linear regression using categorical variable which indicates names of cities

```
library(Rcpp)
library(lme4)

area_csv <- read.csv2('Data/Area.csv')
#area_csv$Value <- as.numeric(area_csv$Value)

py <- read.csv2('Data/Predict_data.csv')

obyem_per_capita_model <- lmList(Value ~ APP * Population | City, data = area_csv)
summary(obyem_per_capita_model)

r_squareds <- summary(obyem_per_capita_model)$r.squared
predictions <- predict(obyem_per_capita_model,newdata = py, asList = TRUE)

#
write.csv2(predictions,'Vvodimoe_Predictions.csv')
```

but when I try to use predict with the new data set which contains all necessary independent variables I get this error:

```
Error in predict.lmList4(obyem_per_capita_model, newdata = py, asList = TRUE) : 
  nonexistent group in 'newdata'
```

Columns in area_csv look like this:
City | Year | Info | Value | Status | Population | APP

Columns in py look like this:
City | Year | Population | APP

Comment: Is their a specific city in your prediction data that is not part of your training data?

Comment: No, all cities which are in prediction set are also present in training set.

Comment: Have you checked `all(py$City %in% area_csv$City)`?

Comment: I think @Roland is right: I managed to reproduce the same error message on simulated data in which there was a level in the test data that was not in the data used to fit the model. It could be a typo in the name of a city, or an unexpected type of data. You could also get a more detailed error message with a simple "lm" and a simpler formula, just to check, like Value ~ APP + Population + City.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a check which was suggested by Roland:

```
all(py$City %in% area_csv$City)
```

And it returned FALSE. Thank you, Roland!   :D

And then I used setdiff to find the difference:

```
setdiff(py$City, area_csv$City)
```

Then, I corrected the typo (removed the difference i.e. nonexistent level in predict data) and it worked!   :D Hurray!   :D
Thank you everyone!   :D